# TableView Section Index not Display

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

I've implemented tableView section index in my app.

TableView Section Index shows when data of tableView is local, When i get data from api call at that time tableview section index hides.

I don't understand why this happening

Here is my tableview section index code:

```
var sectionArray = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current().sectionIndexTitles // section Array

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return memberStructList.count // this is structList
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return memberStructList[section].memberArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MembersHeaderTVCell") as! MembersTVCell
    cell.lblSectionHeader.text = memberStructList[section].sectionName
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 40
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MembersTVCell") as! MembersTVCell
    
    let sectionRows = memberStructList[indexPath.section]
    let row = sectionRows.memberArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblMemberName.text = row.first_name
    
    return cell
}

func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]?
{
    return sectionArray
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String,
               at index: Int) -> Int
{
    if memberStructList.contains(where: {$0.sectionName == title}),
        let sectionIndex = memberStructList.firstIndex(where: {$0.sectionName == title})
    {
        return sectionIndex
    }
    else
    {
        return NSNotFound
    }
}
```

And Here is Structure Code:

```
struct MemberStruct
{
   var sectionName : String
   var memberArray : [MemberModel] = []
}
```

Here is My Webservice Code and MVCServer is My Webservice Function

```
MVCServer().serviceRequestWithURL(reqMethod: .get, withUrl: strUrl, withParam: [:], diplayHud: true, includeToken: true) { (ResponseCode, Response) in
        
        if ResponseCode == 1
        {
            if let array = Response.value(forKeyPath: "payload.data") as? NSArray
            {
                var memberArray = MemberModel.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: array)
                memberArray.forEach({$0.first_name = $0.first_name.capitalized + " " + $0.last_name.capitalized})
                memberArray.sort(){$0.first_name < $1.first_name}
                
                let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: memberArray, by: {String($0.first_name.capitalized.prefix(1))})
                let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()
                self.memberStructList = keys.map({ MemberStruct(sectionName: $0, memberArray: groupedDictionary[$0]!)})
                self.tblMembers.reloadData()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Utility.showToast(messageData: Response)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add the code where you're calling the API and reloading your tableView.

Comment: @PGDev I've update API Code

Comment: Check if `self.memberStructList` is empty after getting the response.

Comment: @PGDev My TableView Shows data that i get from api response, But, TableViewSection Index not shows

Comment: Is the cell class same for HeaderCell and table view cell?

Comment: Yes, Class is Same for both but cell identifier is different

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok with your local data so, I guess You did not follow the priority.
You must set your tableview Delegate and Datasource after receiving the response from webservice.

```
self.tableview.dataSource = self
self.tableview.delegate = self
```

or you should reload your tableview again:

```
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

Comment: I already reload tableview when I receive response from webservice.

Comment: Please check your numberOfRowsInSection count

Comment: My data shows in tableview but tableView Section Index not show

Comment: put your breakPoint on your return sectionIndex line of code and check the property data has value or not

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this instead of using `TableViewCell` on the section header?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18))
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18))
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
    label.text = memberStructList[section].sectionName
    view.addSubview(label)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor() // Set your background color

    return view
}
```